# Exception from .net windows executable file

Tags: .net, entity-framework, installation, dependencies

I have create .net windows application in vs2010 with entity. I have added mydatabase.mdf file in the application to store data. It is working fine when i executed in visual studio. Now I have created setup project and added mydatabase.mdf file after selecting primary output. When i installed this on my computer then i got error "System.Data.EntityException"
with  Stack:

```
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.String, System.String, Boolean ByRef)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
at Macro.BL.ManageMacroGroup.FetchMacroGroups()
at Macro.Macros.IntializeTreeView()
at Macro.Macros..ctor()
at Macro.Program.Main()
```

If some one has idea to handle this then please give me suggestion to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Running from Visual Studio allows you to avoid permission & security issues. Double check your security settings first. Also, the DLL being used in Visual Studio is a different set than the one being used daily ( SDK DLL vs Runtime DLL ). Double check the version used.

Try to Windows Update as well.

Comment: Shivan, i am using windows 7 and i have also tested this on windows xp. Can you please give me some idea to handle this.

Comment: I assumed you are using .NET Framework 4.0, right? As for 1st step, try to update your .NET Framework 4.0 Runtime first.